# find type equality in one array or list and perform operation. C#

Tags: c#, arrays, types, comparison

how can i find type equality in one array. or list
i am using these classes:

```
public class Expression
{
    public Expression[] Par { get; }
    public string Opr { get; }

    public Expression(string opr,params Expression[] par)
    {
        Opr = opr;
        Par = par;
    }

    protected Expression()
    {
    }
}

public class VarExpression : Expression
{
    public char Var { get; set; }
}

public class ConstExpression : Expression
{
    public double Val { get; set; }
}
```

i have `Par` as array type of `Expression`

however one index can be type of `VarExpression` or `ConstExpression`
too ...or just `Expression`

because both `VarExpression` and `ConstExpression` Classes are type of Expression so i need to first check if its `VarExpression` or `ConstExpression` and if its non of them finally its `Expression`.
and finally do some operations on them like adding or whatever and store result in new list an convert to array.
note that i need comparison in one array.

i did search but i couldn't find anything .maybe this question duplicate but i couldn't find anything to get my answer

i already know some ways but i want to know the best, clearest,efficient way with good performance.

the way i know

```
for (int i = 0; i < expression.Par.Length - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < expression.Par.Length; j++)
    {
        if (expression.Par[i] is VarExpression && expression.Par[j] is VarExpression)
        {
            //add and store in list
        }
        else if (expression.Par[i] is ConstExpression && expression.Par[j] is ConstExpression)
        {
            //add and store in list
        }
        else //finaly both or one is only Expression
        {
            //add and store in list
        }
    }
}
// convert list to new array
```

Comment: The double `for` cycle... what are you trying to do? It isn't clear because in the end, if the `expression` is long 10, you'll do 11 * 10 / 2 "add and store in list"

Comment: i want to do algebra.this classes are expressions and now im defining operators. @xanatos

Comment: This might not be relevant to your scenario, but you should know that the BCL has an Expression API to deal with scenarios like the one you are describing. Maybe you could just use that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.expressions(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary You don't normally do all the operations possible for an array of values... What you are doing is for { x, y, 1, 2 }: x + y, x + 1, x + 2, y + 1, y + 2, 1 + 2. Is it really what you want to do?

Comment: You've heard about virtual functions, right? That's where you can apply them.

Comment: no. i want to handle more advanced expressions like 2*x^3+x^2-3x+3...also expression can be inside expression like (x+2)*(x+3)...the one code i wrote is just for addition. @xanatos

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary But that *isn't* what you are doing... The *for* cycle is totally wrong for what you want to do. And even the basic class structure is wrong. The class `Expression` should be called `OperationExpression`, because it has an "Operation", and `VarExpression`/`ConstExpression`  should subclass an `Expression` that is "empty" (does nothing)

Comment: thanks xanatos. where should i define operators + - * /... ? inside Expression? and then how to access properties of OperationExpresion?@xanatos

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Is something like this what you're looking for: http://ideone.com/PXVkQi?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Since these expression trees represent C#, you can even evaluate them automatically. Take a look at this: http://ideone.com/PXVkQi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lambda expressions

```
var vars = expression.Par.Select(x => x.GetType() == typeof(VarExpression)).ToList() ;

var cons = expression.Par.Select(x => x.GetType() == typeof(ConstExpression)).ToList() ;
```

Then you can do wherever you want with your expressions

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple just use the offtype method to get a subset only containing the wanted type.

```
var vars = expression.Par.OfType<VarExpression>()
```

or if you want to process them in a foreach just:

```
foreach (VarExpression variable in expression.Par.OfType<VarExpression>())
{
    //processs
}
```